# SQLPLUS (Oracle) - WHERE subquery to determine if date expression greater than n Days

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am new to SQL and have had some trouble grasping the use of subqueries and where to place them in respect to the outer query. The queries bellow are apart of a problem ive been working on and cant seem to get the desired results.

I need to extract the number of days between a start and end date. Then check if that is greater than 2 and apply that to the outer query. This particular attempt returns "Missing Expression" while other iterations (2nd Query Bellow) have returned an error stating the inner query returns multiple rows.(Modifying to use the "ALL" keyword Did not produce the right results either)

**QUERY1**

```
SELECT P.PETNAME,P.PETTYPE
FROM PETTREATMENT PT, EXAMINATION E, PET P, TREATMENT T
WHERE PT.EXAMNO = E.EXAMNO
AND E.PETNO = P.PETNO
AND PT.TREATNO = T.TREATNO 
AND (SELECT TO_DATE(PETTREATMENT.ENDDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') - TO_DATE(PETTREATMENT.STARTDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS TOTALDAYS FROM PETTREATMENT WHERE TOTALDAYS > 2)
AND T.COST >100
ORDER BY P.PETNAME;
```

**QUERY 2**

```
SELECT P.PETNAME,P.PETTYPE
FROM PETTREATMENT PT, EXAMINATION E, PET P, TREATMENT T
WHERE PT.EXAMNO = E.EXAMNO
AND E.PETNO = P.PETNO
AND PT.TREATNO = T.TREATNO 
AND 2 < (SELECT TO_DATE(PETTREATMENT.ENDDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') - TO_DATE(PETTREATMENT.STARTDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM PETTREATMENT)
AND T.COST >100
ORDER BY P.PETNAME;
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow the question as its currently phrased. Could you please share your tables structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using old-style joins. Because enddate and startdate come from pettreatment table, and you are already selecting from it, you can just specify the condition in the `where` clause. No need for a select.

```
SELECT P.PETNAME,P.PETTYPE
FROM PETTREATMENT PT 
JOIN EXAMINATION E ON PT.EXAMNO = E.EXAMNO
JOIN PET P ON E.PETNO = P.PETNO
JOIN TREATMENT T ON PT.TREATNO = T.TREATNO 
WHERE TO_DATE(PT.ENDDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') - TO_DATE(PT.STARTDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') > 2
AND T.COST > 100
ORDER BY P.PETNAME;
```

Comment: This did the trick,and that explanation makes sense. Are theses joins used here considered natural joins?